# Error installing Community DisplayLink drivers Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, dpkg, displaylink

I am having an issue installing the drivers for the Community DisplayLink

https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian

I'm specifically failing when the evdi package has to be built on the kernel

I am on 20.04 and kernel 5.13

Here is additional logging output:

```
Preparing for install

Archive:  DisplayLink_Ubuntu_5.5.zip
  inflating: 5.5/DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu 5.5.0-59.151-Release Notes.txt  
  inflating: 5.5/displaylink-driver-5.5.0-59.151.run  
Creating directory displaylink-driver-5.5.0-59.151
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.5.0-59.151  100%  
patching file 5.5/displaylink-driver-5.5/displaylink-installer.sh
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line

Installing driver version: 5.5

Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Installing
[ Installing EVDI ]
[[ Installing EVDI DKMS module ]]

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.10.1/source ->
                 /usr/src/evdi-1.10.1

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j16 KERNELRELEASE=5.13.0-43-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/5.13.0-43-generic/build/include KVERSION=5.13.0-43-generic DKMS_BUILD=1...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.10.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-43-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.10.1/build/make.log for more information.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.10.1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
ERROR: Failed to install evdi to the kernel tree.
```

I have disabled Secure Boot as well...
I'm really stuck on this and would like to use another external monitor through my USB ports

Additional output from running `./displaylink-debian.sh --debug`

```
Starting Debug ...

Did you read Post Installation Guide? http://bit.ly/2TbZleK [y/N] y

Did you read Troubleshooting most common issues? http://bit.ly/2Rofd0x [y/N] y

--------------- Linux system info ----------------

Distro: Ubuntu
Release: focal
Kernel: 5.13.0-43-generic

---------------- DisplayLink info ----------------

Driver version: 5.1.26
DisplayLink service status: 
EVDI service version: /sys/devices/evdi/version not found

------------------ Graphics card -----------------

Vendor: i915
Subsystem: Ltd.
VGA: Intel Corporation Device 9a60 (rev 01)
VGA (3D): NVIDIA Corporation Device 25a5 (rev a1)
X11 version: 1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.2

-------------- DisplayLink xorg.conf -------------

File: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf
cat: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-displaylink.conf: No such file or directory
Contents:
 

-------------------- Monitors --------------------

Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 2 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting

-------------------------------------------------------------------

Use this information when submitting an issue (http://bit.ly/2GLDlpY)

-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: See https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/215

Comment: Your other question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408165/use-usb-display-for-external-monitors suggests you don't have any DisplayLink device. A DisplayLink device is an external proprietary chipset that predates even standard USB3.0 and is an external adapter. Some newer USB-C ports also have support for video output but this has NOTHING to do with DisplayLink. Please check the manufacturer's specification to understand if your USB-C port has or hasn't video output.

Comment: https://storage-asset.msi.com/global/picture/faq/10018337@2021-1230-0759-085274@kb_03156_en.pdf

Comment: What are my options for using external displays through USB?
I have a USB-C Gen1

My best option would be to get one of the proper DisplayLink adapters and then using their drivers for additional monitors, since generic USB display adapters (VGA to USB) won't work?

So far, I've searched and my USB-C has the following specs, Type-C USB3.2 Gen1, and searching has provided that these ports are USB display enabled

Comment: No, you're still no understanding it. Granted, it's very confusing. Please check carefully the document above for your EXACT model number. Whether the USB-C port supports video or not has to do with having Thunderbold. You'll notice some models have it and others don't and yet all USB-C ports are of the same generation.

Comment: Thank you for the document. It helped me. It seems I can't have more than one external monitor... which is a big bummer...

Do you know if there are any options of using one HDMI port for multiple displays?

And the different generations of USB-C allow display through them. Like the USB-C Gen2 are capable of doing multiple external displays

Or is my only option buying the DisplayLink adapter and getting their drivers to work if I want to use USB display?

Comment: I have installed these drivers successfully
They have finally been made to work properly on my version of ubuntu and kernel :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use USB display for external monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408165/use-usb-display-for-external-monitors)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue after installing the [DisplayLink drivers](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu) for the Dell D3100 Docking Station after some Kernel update.

```
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.10.1 not found
```

It worked out after installing the DKMS via Aptitude.

```
sudo aptitude install dkms
```

Hope it helps.